# If check.torproject.org shows congratulations message, that means my setup is working correctly?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, torcheck

*Warning: It may looks like stupid question.*

I use `Expert Bundle` instead of `Tor Browser` and config Firefox to use it (*I have my reasons*). now when I visit https://check.torproject.org/ I see following message *in beautiful green color*:

> Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.

That means my config is correct and using this method is same as using `Tor Browser`?

P.S: I know in `Tor Browser` there is *I think* no script addon installed and some other configs that helps better protection, I don't mean that kind of compare here.

Comment: Can you clarify your last paragraph? You ask if it’s the same as using the Tor Browser, but then you say you know it’s not the same. What kind of comparison are you looking for?

Comment: @Steve I want to focus only on Tor itself here, let's say I config Firefox exact same as Tor Browser (and install the same set of addon), now using `Expert Bundle` is the same as using `Tor Browser`? (I think Tor is more than just Tor Browser and is not depend on it, so that's way I wrote the last part)